# Is there a way I can stop Ammo from auto-stacking with what I have equipped when I craft it?

Tags: factorio

I'm playing *First Steps* and I am on the third level. When I built my first Gun Turret ,I got confused at first because while I had ammo for my Sub-Machine gun and just crafted a new batch, nothing showed up when I went to load my Turret.

I thought then that I miss-identified the icon and the Turret needed a gun but eventually I learned that the ammo didn't turn up because it was stacked with what I had equipped.

So is there a way I can stop Ammo from auto-stacking with what I have equipped when I craft it?

Comment: I think If you are equipped with maximum ammo, it should go into your inventory instead.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you do have some options to mitigate this.

- As Timmy Jim says, if you have max ammo (100 in 0.14, 200 in 0.15), extra ammo crafted will go into your inventory.
- You can also load the turret from your Submachine Gun ammo.  An easy way is click on the turret, then shift-right-click on the ammo to load in half.
- Later on, you will be able to craft different types of ammo, which will not stack and thus always be in your inventory.